# Neo4j data loading performance: driver vs custom procedure

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I'm switching from Neo4j Java custom procedures to an approach based on the Neo4j Java driver. I want to end up with some sort of microservice running my graph algorithm, instead of calling the custom procedure through Cypher. I implemented the traversal using a bunch of standard HashMaps: Once the data is loaded from Neo4j to these HashMaps, the graph traversal is much faster than in my original custom procedure, so that's very promising.

Now to my question: Within the custom procedure I was able to load the graph (40 mio edges, 10 mio nodes) to the Hashmaps like so:

```java
@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;
...

HashMap<Long, Long> mapNodeIdProperty = new HashMap<>();
db.beginTx().getAllNodes().stream().forEach((org.neo4j.graphdb.Node n) 
              -> mapNodeIdProperty.put(n.getId(),
                     (Long) n.getProperty("combProp")));
```

This takes about a minute, which I consider acceptable as the service's start-up time.

Now, the best solution I could find using the driver goes something like this:

```java
driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, AuthTokens.basic( user, password ) );

...

try ( Session session = driver.session() )
{
    String status = session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public String execute( Transaction tx )
        {
            Stream<Record> resultStream = (Stream<Record>) tx.run(
                           "MATCH (n) RETURN n").stream();
            resultStream.forEach((Record n) -> listNodes.add(((Record) n).get("n").asNode()));
            return "ok; length=" + listNodes.size();
        }
    });
    System.out.println( status);
}
```

This takes too much time, even if I limit the number of returned nodes to just a few thousand using the cypher query. I never waited for the full graph to load.

What would be my best bet for getting the same speed using the driver (or alternative approaches ) as compared the stored procedure? Are there fundamental limitations which would inhibit this?

Comment: why are you doing this in the first case?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks, fair point, that was a bad example to illustrate the approach using the custom procedure. In the end I do pull certain properties from all nodes (see updated question) and create nested HashMaps to represent the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As InverseFalcon points out, the transfer over the bolt protocol comes with speed limitations, not present in procedures. What I was looking for is the embedded DBMS described [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/java-embedded/include-neo4j/). I am now using this like this:

```java
public class GraphAccess implements AutoCloseable
{
    ...

    private final DatabaseManagementService managementService =
        new DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder(NEO4J_DATA_PATH)
        .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.read_only, true )
                        .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.logs_directory,
                                   NEO4J_LOGS_DIRECTORY).build();
    public final GraphDatabaseService db = managementService.database( NEO4J_DATABASE_NAME );

    public final HashMap<Integer, String> mapNodeProp = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    private void getNodeData() {

        try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() ) {
            tx.getAllNodes().forEach((Node n) -> {
                
                final Integer nodeId = (int) n.getId();
                mapNodeProp.put(nodeId, (String) n.getProperty("name"));
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of high throughput (since it doesn't use the driver, but accesses the neo4j database data directly) and the possibility to use it in the context of a Spring app (since it's not implemented as a custom procedure).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that procedure code executes on the server itself, it is effectively embedded with Neo4j.

Compare that to the need to transfer all nodes and their properties over the network. That's a lot of extra I/O that wasn't needed with procedures.

Comment: In the embedded case it doesn't load any properties it basically just puts the wrapper around the id in the map as a value.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thanks, makes sense. Is there a way to combine the kind of direct access of the procedure code with, say, a spring server (which would allow  me to pull all relevant data from the database once and then keep it in memory)? I came across the `DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder` by now, which seems to be what I'm looking for, since it can be initialized with a database directory without going through the driver. Is this accurate?